# Algorithm for finding most present value in containers

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, containers

I have the following problem I have a vector of `std::set`'s now I want to compute the element, which is in the most of the sets.
For example:
If the sets are {1,2,3,4}, {2,4,5} and {2,7,8} i want the algorithm to output 2, because 2 is in 3 sets and every other element isnt.
My current attempt in solving this uses a map, which maps a counter tovevery value in the sets and then iterates over all the sets.
I am sure I need to iterate over all the sets, but can I solve this using some algorithms in the `<algorithm>` header?

Comment: It'd be good if you included your "manual" map solution for reference.

Comment: @hyde why? it's easy enough to guess what it does.

Comment: @Ven For one, it's much easier to write answer code, when there is existing template with correct variables etc. Two, questions with relevant code are simply more likely to get upvotes (which is helpful for getting good answers), because code. Three, it helps to demonstrate the OP actually understands what they are asking about and "have done their homework" before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using `for_each`:

```
std::set<std::set<std::string>> sets {s1,s2,s3,s4}; // incurs a copy on each set
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> all;
std::for_each(sets.begin(), sets.end(), [&all](const std::set<std::string> &s) { // outer loop: each set in sets
    std::for_each(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), [&all](const std::string &string) { // nested loop
         all[string]++;
    });
});
for (const auto &p : all)
    std::cout << p.first << " = " << p.second << "\n";
```

[See it live on Coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b799da9bf33f3b9a)

Another solution using a single vector and accumulate:

```
std::set<std::string> s1 {"a", "b", "c"};
std::set<std::string> s2 {"a", "x", "d"};
std::set<std::string> s3 {"a", "y", "d"};
std::set<std::string> s4 {"a", "z", "c"};
std::vector<std::string> vec;
// flatten sets into the vector.
vec.insert(vec.begin(), s1.begin(), s1.end());
vec.insert(vec.begin(), s2.begin(), s2.end());
vec.insert(vec.begin(), s3.begin(), s3.end());
vec.insert(vec.begin(), s4.begin(), s4.end());
for (const auto &p : std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::unordered_map<std::string, int>{}, [](auto& c, std::string s) { c[s]++; return c; })) // accumulate the vector into a map
    std::cout << p.first << " = " << p.second << "\n";
```

[See it live on Coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d80b4d0589645fac)

If the cost of the copy is too big a burden, you can instead use a partially-applied function on each of the `std::set`s:

```
std::set<std::string> s1 {"a", "b", "c"};
std::set<std::string> s2 {"a", "x", "d"};
std::set<std::string> s3 {"a", "y", "d"};
std::set<std::string> s4 {"a", "z", "c"};
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> all;
auto count = [&all](const auto& set) { std::for_each(set.begin(), set.end(), [&all](std::string s) { all[s]++; }); };
count(s1); // apply a for_each on each set manually.
count(s2);
count(s3);
count(s4);
for (const auto &p : all)
    std::cout << p.first << " = " << p.second << "\n";
```

[See it live on Coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2e4591c62de9746)

Answer (score 2):

And calculating the intersections:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s1{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::set<int> s2{ 2, 4, 5 };
    std::set<int> s3{ 2, 7, 8 };

    std::multiset<int> s4;

    std::set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
        std::insert_iterator<std::multiset<int>>(s4, s4.begin()));

    std::set_intersection(s4.begin(), s4.end(), s3.begin(), s3.end(),
        std::insert_iterator<std::multiset<int>>(s4, s4.begin()));

    auto max = std::max_element(s4.begin(), s4.end(),
        [&s4](int a, int b) { return s4.count(a) < s4.count(b); });

    std::cout << "most present == " << *max << '\n';
}
```

Comment: For large problem instances, it would seem advisable to always intersect the two sets of lowest cardinality - which after the first step means _current intersection with the smallest set not handled yet_.

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` is ordered. So the following codes may be a little faster.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

typedef std::set<int> Data;
typedef std::vector<Data> DataSet;
typedef std::vector<int> Result;

Result findIntersection(const DataSet& sets) {
    Result is; // intersection
    std::vector<Data::iterator> its;
    for (int i = 0; i < sets.size(); ++i) {
        its.push_back(sets[i].begin());
    }

    if (its.size() == 0) return is;
    if (its.size() == 1) {
        // return sets[0];
        return is;
    }

    while(its[0] != sets[0].end()) {
        const int sentinel = *its[0];
        int counter = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < its.size(); ++j) {
            while (*its[j] < sentinel && its[j] != sets[j].end()) ++its[j];
            if (its[j] == sets[j].end()) return is;
            if (*its[j] != sentinel) break;
            ++its[j];
            ++counter;
        }

        if (counter == its.size()) is.push_back(sentinel);
        ++its[0];
    }

    return is;
}

int main() {
    Data s1{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    Data s2{ 2, 4, 5 };
    Data s3{ 2, 4, 7, 8 };
    DataSet data = {s1, s2, s3};

    Result is = findIntersection(data);
    std::copy(is.begin(), is.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```